# Reedireccion de pagina con html

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

la verdad no creo que necesiten codigo para intentar responder mi pregunta, lo que hice fue un formulario de login , y un formulario de registro, los 2 estan enlazados a la misma base de datos en php, lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de que tu introduzcas los datos correctamente te lleve a el formulario de registro, el formulario de login tiene su propio proyecto de brackets y el de registro tambien esta en una carpeta distinta, que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun entiendo, lo que necesitas es que la validacion con la BD es satisfactoria, encontes te direccione a tu proyecto, siendo asi, entonces seria desde `php` asi:

```
if(validacion== false){

  //esta es una ruta relativa que depende de la geraquia de las carpetas
  //si estas dentro de una capeta y debes sali precedelo de ../ para sali
  header("location: carptea/brackets.php");

}else{


 //si no se cumple la validacion re direcciona al mismo loguin o formulario
     header("location: login.php");
    }
```

espero te sirva y la marques xD... ReNiceCode...

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio mucho

Comment: me alegro mucho bro, marca la respuesta como valida para que las nuevas generaciones que venga en busca de la misma pregunta la vean @Jesús ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer la validación con php y llamar a una función en Javascript para redireccionar a la pagina de registro de esta manera:

`function redirect_Reg() {
    location.href = "../ProyectoRegistro/pagRegistro.html";
}`

Comment: creo que el valida desde php

Comment: Exelente, gracias por tu ayuda